# How do i get code completion for C# scripts in VSCode for Unity on Linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I recently came back to unity, as i found out that it does now support installation linux. It works, but when editing the scripts with vscode i do not get code completion.

I have installed the C# extension, the Debugger for unity extension and the Unity Code Snippets extension.

I know that there is the Visual Studio IntelliCode extension, but this does only support Java, Python js and ts. I also know that there are IDEs that i can use, like Rider, but i would like to setup this in a lightweight environment without an IDE.

So, how do i setup code completion in vscode for unity-scripts on linux?

Comment: Did you ever manage to get it working? I have a similar problem using MacOS 11.6.1 (Intel). Installed VS Code, dotnet and Mono, restarted and managed to generate the csproj and sln files, but I still can't get code completion.

Comment: I never got it to work, sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this guide](https://nosuchstudio.medium.com/setting-up-unity-2019-x-with-vscode-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-a-troubleshooting-guide-75da7ff29ff5)

1. Install Unity Editor
2. Install Visual Studio Code
   3.Tell Unity to use VSCode

> n project preferences -> external tools you can tell Unity what program to use for editing c# scripts. If you have the Visual Studio Editor packages in your project, you should see a special “Visual Studio Code” option in your preferences. The packages are part of the standard Unity download now.

4. Install dotnet
5. Install mono-complete

Most people forget step 3

Comment: I already had done all these steps, except of step 5. After installing mono-complete, nothing changes. Still no completion of "public" when typing "pub" or completion of "GameObject" when typing "GameObj".

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything in the [installation guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity), but code completion would still not work.

Somewhere I read that setting ***Use Global Mono*** to `always` in the [C# extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) might fix the problem. So I did that, restarted Unity, Unity Hub and VS Code, and then it started working correctly.

[image]